# loading data from mongo into select element

Tags: select, mongoose, element

I am trying to load data from mongo into select element on the webpage but the web page gets loaded before the data is available apparently that is how node.js works. 
Please how can I get data loaded into select element in my webpage using the data coming from my mongodb.
How can I load data into my webpage after the webpage is fully loaded 
I am using express and mongoose

Comment: See axios for ajax calls

Comment: @Helping hand thank for your help it was what i was looking for